# PHP Script leads to Error 500 only on one script, even if I comment everything

Tags: php, apache

I get everytime Error 500. I tried to comment everything but nothing won't help. Where could be the problem? I use a normal apache2 server on Ubuntu. Even if I write the beginning tag like

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

mysql_connect("192.168.3.64", "root", "xxx");
mysql_select_db("vertretung");

function rollback_if_error() {
    if(mysql_error()) {
        mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
        die("error");
    }
}

mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");

$table_id = rand();

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tables (table_id, table_date, table_name) VALUES ($table_id, '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['table_date'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['table_name'])."')");
rollback_if_error();

$table_rows = explode("|", $_POST['table_data']);

$is_caption = true;

foreach($table_rows as $row) {
    $row_id = rand();

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_rows (row_id, table_id, is_caption) VALUES ($row_id, $table_id, ".$is_caption.")");
    rollback_if_error();

    $fields = explode(";", $row);

    foreach($row as $field) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_field (row_id, value) VALUES ($row_id, '".mysql_real_escape_string($field)."')");
        rollback_if_error();
    }

    $is_caption = false;
}

mysql_query("COMMIT");
?>
```

Comment: did you checked your htaccess file etc..

Comment: An error 500 usually suggests a server fault. Maybe there is something wrong with your .htaccess (if you use any) or with your general server configuration. Or maybe ownership or rights or something is messed up. That could be fixed by deleting the file and creating it again.

Comment: There is no .htaccess file... at least not in /var/www. Ok how can i force him to recreate the files if i may ask?

Comment: Have you checked the log in `/var/log/httpd` or in `/var/log/apache2`?

Answer (score 0):

Generally error 500 occurred from server fault but sometime this issue came from php error not display. try this

```
ini_set("display_errors","On");
error_reporing(-1); // or E_ALL
```

put this lines on top of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check apache & php error_logs, it will tell everything you need to know